# How do I pull an extra row when pulling data from between dates?

Tags: sqlite

I'd like to pull another row with the nearest date before the beginning of the following query from a sqlite db:

`select * from inv WHERE TIME BETWEEN date1 AND date2`

Is there a simple addition to the query or do I need to pull in more data and do the transformation at the end?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UNION` for the row with the maximum `TIME` that is less than `date1`:

```
select * from inv WHERE TIME BETWEEN date1 AND date2
UNION
select * from inv WHERE TIME = (select MAX(TIME) from inv WHERE TIME < date1)
```

If there would be more than 1 additional rows and you want exactly 1, you can add to the above code:

```
LIMIT 1
```